# short perl script to crawl several links and extract data

Tags: perl

I've been looking everywhere but I couldn't find what I was looking for. I also tried coding it myself using WWW:Mechanize but I guess too many stuff are missing. So what I'm trying to do is pretty simple. 
I have a website with several links and several pages. Each link is a report with some random data.
So I want to be able to access each links and extract data from the accessed pages and print that out in a text file.
I just need some tips on how to do that I can take care of the rest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [WWW::Mechanize example program `ccdl`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW%3a%3aMechanize%3a%3aExamples#ccdl,_by_Andy_Lester). I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LWP::Simple` if you know what are the links to access and Use `HTML::TokeParser::Simple` to parse the documents